# direct buffer memory setting

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm using 64-bit JDK and when testing with the default JVM setting, occures the error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory

I googled and found that I need to set the max direct buffer memory with the param -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize for java

System: windows 7

I'm running a bash shell on the git shell,

```
 $./bin/local.sh local.xml
```

the question  is:
 how can I set the XX:MaxDirectMemorySize on the git shell command line?
Or shall I set the param in some jvm file?

confused about this, please help

Comment: You set this param just like you set all your other params. Question is: how *do* you set other params? Is the program under your control? Or third party? How do you launch it?

Comment: @Ordous the program under my control  I use it like this $./bin/local.sh -c conf/local.xml   under the git shell console

Comment: Now I might be stating the obvious here, but `local.sh` doesn't look like `java` to me. All you've said in your comment is what the file to launch it is called. **The name of the file does not help one bit**.

Comment: @Ordous mayby I did not describe my question pertinently. So what should I do if I want to set the XX:MaxDirectMemorySize param?

Comment: The best way to do it would be to put it into your java call. But that might not be possible if you don't have direct access to the call (i.e. you call it via a script that was given to you and you can't modify it). That's why I was asking the questions - *how do you launch the application?*. Saying you launch it from a shell or that you launch it with `local.sh` is like answering "What kind of car do you have?" with "It's a red one!". You have to actually look into the local.sh and see what it does. And maybe look into scripts deeper if it uses them until you actually find the call to the JVM

Comment: @Ordous thank you very much, seems I did not do the right thing, I mean I should detect the local.sh for more. thank you very much. talk to you later.

Comment: @Ordous I resolved this issue, I put this param XX:MaxDirectMemorySize in the local.sh where exec the Java command. this param should work with Java command line.